Go-to rsync command to sync local repo with changes on remote one
I cloned a git repo from a custom gitlab hosting on a remote machine but I can't push from there without my private key (I'm using ssh). Since I don't want to expose it on a remote server I thought about syncing the repo or changs down to the one I have on my local machine and pushing from there. Is there any recommended way of doing this?
I figured I could just use rsync on the whole folder, but the -a flag also updates the timestamps. So I wonder what are the recommended flags? Afaik I don't need to preserve permissions and ownership, but git keeps the executable flag apparently, so how to do that? What are the recommended flags for rsyncing the repo?

@phd I hope it's more clear now.

@phd I think you misunderstood. I don't want to rsync to gitlab, gitlab is not part of this.  The original repo just lives on gitlab and I pulled it down on two hosts, one of which is the remote server and one my local machine. Now I want to rsync from the remote server to my local machine because I did the changes there. I could create an extra gitlab key but I don't want to if I can avoid it.

@phd Isn't there a difference between a platform that hosts the repo (like github/ gitlab) and a host that just has the repo lying around on the filesystem? I think my remote would need to expose some form of an api to act as an actual git remote, no? Or how would you specify the path to the remote in remote add?

I think you're giving just AI answers. Can you give a concrete example of how such a git pull command would look like if I was to pull from a remote server (not gitlab, github, just a normal server)?

@phd Deleting all your answers doesn't really help to convince me otherwise.
